# Trying to initialize an edge struct which is inside the district struct. How do I do that?

Tags: c++, struct

This is the district struct with the edge struct inside.

```
    /**
 * district struct that keeps track of the name, valence, and connections a district has to others
 */
struct district {
    /**
     * contains an edge with two vertices
     */
    struct edge {
        district *vertex1, *vertex2;
        /**
         * initializes both vertices to nullptr
         */
        edge() :
                vertex1(nullptr), vertex2(nullptr) {
        }
    };
    T name;
    int valence;
    edge *connection[100];
    int color;
    /**
     * initializes all struct members to default values
     */
    district(T name) :
            name(name), valence(0), connection { nullptr }, color(100) {
    }
};
```

I'm attempting to create edges between vertices like this:

```
    list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence]->vertex1 = list[i];
    list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence]->vertex2 = list[j];
    list[i]->valence++; //add 1 to the amount of vertices for district a
    list[j]->connection[list[j]->valence]->vertex1 = list[j];
    list[j]->connection[list[j]->valence]->vertex2 = list[i];
    list[j]->valence++; //add 1 to the amount of vertices for district b
    sort(); //sort the list in order of valence
```

But in order to write data to that edge, it needs to be created first with the "new" operator, as far as I understand.  The districts are already initialized further up in the code to their respective places in the list array if they didn't exist there already, and I don't need help with that.

I attempted several different ways of creating a new edge:

```
    list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence] = new district.edge;
    list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence] = new district->edge;
    list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence] = new edge;
```

But none of them work.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Try `district::edge`. (Not sure enough to write an answer.)

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  I tried to create a district::edge *e1, and I got this error:  "dependent-name ‘graph<T>::district:: edge’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new way to create `district::edge` in C++11:

First: get a object `e` of `district::edge`:
`auto e = *(p);//p is a pointer of district::edge and it point to a real object of district::edge`

Second: deduce `district::edge` form the object `e`:
`using edge = decltype(e);`

Now, `edge` is the type `district::edge`.

We can write code like this:
`list[i]->connection[list[i]->valence] = new edge();`

note: This is a common way to get unknown type in C++11.

Comment: This method gives me no compiler errors, but the program crashes when it gets to `auto e = *(list[i]->connection[0]);`

Comment: I ran it in the debugger, and it gives no error report for the crash.  It simply terminates the program.

Comment: @Morgan code `auto e = *(list[i]->connection[0]);` run error is because  ** `*(list[i]->connection[0]);` is not a real object**. Are you sure it?

Comment: Why would you go through all that if you already know the type?  just say new district::edge like @tuple_cat says in the other answer.

Comment: @xaxxon We didn't know the type, we just have an object of the type. Do you know what I mean.

Comment: @joe i don't see that in the question.  Look at the last section of code listed -- the way he says he's tried have the type -- he just has the wrong punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> new district.edge
> ```

No, `district` is not an object.

> ```
> new district->edge
> ```

No, `district` is not a pointer.

> ```
> new edge
> ```

No type named `edge` in scope. (Unless you do this inside a member function of `district`.)

Instead, use the **scope resolution operator `::`**:

```
new district::edge
```